# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'y_tensor:0', which has shape '(?,)'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I implemented an RNN to perform sentiment analysis and I want to create a function that will find sentiment on custom input but I get a value error. Here is my function:

```
def find_sentiment(text, trained):
    # print(text)
    review_array = np.array(list(vocab_processor.fit_transform(text)))
    # vocab_dict = vocab_processor.vocabulary_._mapping
    # print(vocab_dict)
    # print(review_array)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, "saved/model.ckpt")

        print(sess.run([prediction], {x: review_array, y: trained[0]}))


find_sentiment(["I am very disappointed"], train_target)
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andreas/sentiment_analysis_with_rnn/sentiment_analysis_rnn.py", line 177, in <module>
    find_sentiment(["I am very disappointed"], train_target)
  File "/home/andreas/sentiment_analysis_with_rnn/sentiment_analysis_rnn.py", line 174, in find_sentiment
    print(sess.run([prediction], {x: review_array, y: trained[0]}))
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1100, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape () for Tensor 'y_tensor:0', which has shape '(?,)'
```

When I use trained instead of trained[0] there is no error but I do not want that. How can I fix it? I already tried trained[0].reshape(1)

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide the shape of trained[0] by for example printing `trained[0].shape` and the code where you define`y`.

Comment: trained[0].shape has a shape of ()

Comment: `trained[0].reshape(?, 1)`